How do I add a border between two flex items?
I'm trying to add a border between two row flex items, however whenever I add one, the flex items stay in top of eachother instead of being next to eachother, here is an example:
This is how I want it to look. (line was drawn in paint, not a real thing)

https://i.sstatic.net/M6PQW26p.png
This is what I get.

https://i.sstatic.net/JkcXXx2C.png
<body>
    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="flex-item1">
            <p>Flex content</p>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-item2">
            <p>Flex content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    height: 100vh;
    .flex-item1 {
        flex: 1 50%;
        background-color: aqua;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .flex-item2 {
        flex: 1 50%;
        background-color: white;
    }
}


I think this link will help you:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#aa-flex-direction

Do you need the wrap property?  nowrap would display both flex-items in a row.

Remove flex-flow css.

Because by default your flex elements have box-sizing: content-box; and border adds up to 50% of your 2px.
I advise you to always start with * { box-sizing: border-box }:


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  height: 100vh;
}

.flex-item1 {
  flex: 1 50%;
  background-color: aqua;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.flex-item2 {
  flex: 1 50%;
  background-color: white;
}
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item1">
    <p>Flex content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item2">
    <p>Flex content</p>
  </div>
</div>



If you intentionally want to use box-sizing: content-box; then do this:


.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  height: 100vh;
}

.flex-item1 {
  flex: 1 calc(50% - 2px); /* <--- */
  background-color: aqua;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.flex-item2 {
  flex: 1 50%;
  background-color: white;
}
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item1">
    <p>Flex content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item2">
    <p>Flex content</p>
  </div>
</div>



